# ValueError with file concatanation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

new to Python so bare with. I have a folder with 20,000 csvs in the ones that are important to me start with `'IC'` and end in `prev_date + '.csv'`. I am trying to find a way to concatanate all of these into one file if, when the above start and end filters are applied, it concatenates.

```
import os

prev_date = str('20190624')
csv_header = 'Index no,date,thesis,quantity'
csv_out = 'R:/Sam/simulator/consolidated_positions.csv'

csv_dir = 'R:/Sam/simulator/'

dir_tree = csv_dir
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in dir_tree:
    pass

csv_list = []
for file in filenames:
    if file.endswith(prev_date + '.csv') and file.startswith('IC'):
        csv_list.append(file)

csv_merge = open(csv_out, 'w')
csv_merge.write(csv_header)
csv_merge.write('\n')

for file in csv_list:
    csv_in = open(file)
    for line in csv_in:
        if line.startswith(csv_header):
            continue
        csv_merge.write(line)
    csv_in.close()
    csv_merge.close()
print('Verify consolidated CSV file : ' + csv_out)
```

The issue being i keep getting the project folder back in the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:/Sam/Project/Branch/concatanator.py", line 10, in <module>
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in dir_tree:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

I think it has something to do with it expected relative filepaths, not the actual I  provided.

Also, if possible, if anyone there a quick hint on how to exclude the files if they have the word `EXTRA` anywhere within the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line of your code

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in dir_tree:
```

to this, using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_tree):
```

---

As for your second question:

> Also, if possible, if anyone there a quick hint on how to exclude the files if they have the word EXTRA anywhere within the file name?

you could try this:

```
for file in filenames:
    if 'EXTRA' not in file:
        if file.endswith(prev_date + '.csv') and file.startswith('IC'):
            csv_list.append(file)
```

---

Final code (you should use `os.path.join(dirpath, file)` to get the full file path):

```
csv_list = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(csv_dir):
    for file in filenames:
        if 'EXTRA' not in file:
            if file.endswith(prev_date + '.csv') and file.startswith('IC'):
                csv_list.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```

Comment: Nice, seems like we made progress, but now saying

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:/Sam/Project/Branch/concatanator.py", line 23, in <module>
    csv_in = open(file)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IC_testingfun_20190624.csv'

Process finished with exit code 1`

However I thought I was telling it to look in a different folder?

Comment: I think, I have enticed you into an error bigger than previously mentioned because now has a traceback of:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "R:/Sam/Project/Branch/concatanator.py", line 29, in <module>
    csv_merge.write(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: @SamHarper you probably should un-indent the line `csv_merge.close()`; it should go outside of the loop.

Comment: Which is now fixed since I un-indented! Literally, thank you so much! You have helped me incredibly today! Have a great day!